# xsl: when expression with boolean datatype

Tags: xslt

I am having a problem with an xsl:when statement using a boolean datatype.  As you can see when I use a boolean expression with another datatype and use a boolean expression to test that the attribute  "exists"  (Phone/@Type), it works, but when I use a test...="'true'" expression or it's opposite I get either "no" for both records or "yes" for both records instead of 1 yes and 1 no.  I've tried a number of variations on the test expression based on answers I found here.  As part of the exercise I'm doing, the IsManager attribute is supposed to be boolean, not just the expression testing it.

Here's my xml:

```
 <Person IsManager="true">
  <FirstName>Alex</FirstName>
  <LastName>Chilton</LastName>
  <Phone Type="Cell">555-1212</Phone>
  <IM>Alex1092</IM>
```

And the second record:

```
<Person>
  <FirstName>Laura</FirstName>
  <LastName>Chilton</LastName>
  <Phone>555-5678</Phone>
  <IM>LaurethSulfate</IM>
```

Here's the xsl:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="//Person">
       <tr>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="LastName"/></td>
        <xsl:choose> 
          <xsl:when test="boolean(Phone/@Type)">
             <td><xsl:value-of select="Phone/@Type"/></td>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <td>Home</td>
          </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Phone"/></td> 
          <td><xsl:value-of select="IM"/></td>
        <xsl:choose>     
          <xsl:when test="(Person/@IsManager)='true'">
            <td>Yes</td>  
          </xsl:when>   
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <td>No</td>      
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
       </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

And here's the result:

First Name Last Name Phone Type Phone IM Manager 
Alex Chilton Cell 555-1212 Alex1092 No 
Laura Chilton Home 555-5678 LaurethSulfate No

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You're inside a `for-each select="//Person"` so the context node is a `Person` element.  Therefore instead of

```
<xsl:when test="(Person/@IsManager)='true'">
```

you need just

```
<xsl:when test="@IsManager='true'">
```

Note that this is not comparing to a boolean as such, it's comparing the value of the `IsManager` attribute to the *string* "true".